# Cannot Display Mulitple Charts using Google Charts? php/html website

Tags: php, html, charts, google-visualization

I am currently coding a web app using html and php. I have a MYSQL database on phpmyadmin. I am trying to display some charts using data from tables in this database on one of the site pages. I have a php file dbconnect which connects to the database. I manage to get the first pie chart displaying and working fine but as soon as I tried to add in the second chart 'deadlinechart' it stopped working and now displays nothing. It is obviously something to do with that second lot of code but I cannot see what is different and stopping it from displaying. Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: index.php');
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: index.php");
}

?>

<?php include ('dbconnect.php') ?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT plan, COUNT(*) as number FROM evals GROUP BY plan";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
?>

<?php
$query2 = "SELECT deadlineMet, COUNT (*) as number FROM evals GROUP BY deadlineMet";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>UPM</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawPlanChart);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDeadline);

        function drawPlanChart()
        {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Plan', 'Number'],
                <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "['".$row["plan"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";

                    }
                ?>
                ]);
            var options = {
                title: 'How often you have stuck to your original plan'
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('planchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        }

        function drawDeadline()
        {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['DeadlineMet', 'Number'],
                <?php
                    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                        echo "['".$row2["deadlineMet"]."', ".$row2["number"]."],";
                    }
                ?>

            ]);
            var options = {
                title: 'Did you meet the deadline'
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('deadlinechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>

    <style>

        .jumbotron {
            background-color: #f4511e;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 100px 25px;

        }

        .bg-grey{
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }

        .container-fluid{
            padding: 60px 50px;
        }

        .logo {
            font-size: 200px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

            .col-sm-4 {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 25px 0;
            }

        }

        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: #f4511e;
            z-index: 9999;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 12px !important;
            line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
            color: #f4511e !important;
            background-color: #fff !important;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
            border-color: transparent;
            color: #fff !important;

        }

    </style>
</head>



<body id="Evaluations" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">



<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand">

                <!-- logo not working-->

                <!-- <IMG SRC="images/UPMLogo.jpg" width="230px" height="158px">-->

            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li><a href="home.php">HOME</a></li>

                <li><a href="myprojects.php">MY PROJECTS</a></li>

                <li><a href="eval.php">EVALUATIONS</a></li>

                <li><a href="stats.php">MY STATS</a></li>

                <li><a href="hints.php">HINTS & TIPS</a></li>

                <li><a href="home.php?logout='1'">LOG OUT</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</nav>



<div class="jumbotron text-center">

    <h1 id =SiteTitle> Welcome to your Evaluations page! </h1>

    <h3>Here you can evaluate your project management skills based on completed projects. Over time you will hopefully be able to build up a pattern of your project management and look for how to improve it!</h3>

</div>


<div class=""container-fluid">

<p>
    To get add an evaluation click on the plus symbol!
</p>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form method="post" action="eval.php">

                <div class=""input-group>
                    Project Title :<br>
                    <input type="text" name="projtitle2"><br>
                </div>
                <div class=""input-group>
                    Did you meet the deadline? :<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="deadline" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="deadline" value="no"> No<br>
                </div>
                <div class=""input-group>
                    Did you stick to your original plan without any changes? :<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="no"> No<br>
                </div>
                <div class=""input-group>
                    Did you fully understand the scope of the project from the beginning? :<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="scope" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="scope" value="no"> No<br>
                </div>
                <div class=""input-group>
                    What was your final grade for the project? : <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="A" checked> A<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="B"> B<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="C" checked> C<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="D"> D<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="E" checked> E<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="F"> F<br>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="addeval">+</button>
                <p><strong>Click me to add your self evaluation!</strong></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="planchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="deadlinechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of ways to define the google charts callback
try combining the callback into one function as part of the `load` statement,
like so...

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ['corechart'],
      callback: function () {
        drawPlanChart();
        drawDeadline();
      }
    });
```

---

**EDIT**

replacing the php with hard-coded values seems to work fine,
see following working...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: function () {
    drawPlanChart();
    drawDeadline();
  }
});

function drawPlanChart()
{
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Plan', 'Number'],
      ['A', 1],
      ['B', 2],
      ['C', 3],
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'How often you have stuck to your original plan'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('planchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawDeadline()
{
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['DeadlineMet', 'Number'],
      ['A', 1],
      ['B', 2],
      ['C', 3],
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Did you meet the deadline'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('deadlinechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>UPM</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <style>

        .jumbotron {
            background-color: #f4511e;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 100px 25px;

        }

        .bg-grey{
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }

        .container-fluid{
            padding: 60px 50px;
        }

        .logo {
            font-size: 200px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

            .col-sm-4 {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 25px 0;
            }

        }

        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: #f4511e;
            z-index: 9999;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 12px !important;
            line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
            color: #f4511e !important;
            background-color: #fff !important;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
            border-color: transparent;
            color: #fff !important;

        }

    </style>
</head>



<body id="Evaluations" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">



<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand">

                <!-- logo not working-->

                <!-- <IMG SRC="images/UPMLogo.jpg" width="230px" height="158px">-->

            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li><a href="home.php">HOME</a></li>

                <li><a href="myprojects.php">MY PROJECTS</a></li>

                <li><a href="eval.php">EVALUATIONS</a></li>

                <li><a href="stats.php">MY STATS</a></li>

                <li><a href="hints.php">HINTS & TIPS</a></li>

                <li><a href="home.php?logout='1'">LOG OUT</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</nav>



<div class="jumbotron text-center">

    <h1 id =SiteTitle> Welcome to your Evaluations page! </h1>

    <h3>Here you can evaluate your project management skills based on completed projects. Over time you will hopefully be able to build up a pattern of your project management and look for how to improve it!</h3>

</div>


<div class=""container-fluid">

<p>
    To get add an evaluation click on the plus symbol!
</p>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form method="post" action="eval.php">

                <div class=""input-group>
                    Project Title :<br>
                    <input type="text" name="projtitle2"><br>
                </div>
                <div class=""input-group>
                    Did you meet the deadline? :<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="deadline" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="deadline" value="no"> No<br>
                </div>
                <div class=""input-group>
                    Did you stick to your original plan without any changes? :<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="plan" value="no"> No<br>
                </div>
                <div class=""input-group>
                    Did you fully understand the scope of the project from the beginning? :<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="scope" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="scope" value="no"> No<br>
                </div>
                <div class=""input-group>
                    What was your final grade for the project? : <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="A" checked> A<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="B"> B<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="C" checked> C<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="D"> D<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="E" checked> E<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="F"> F<br>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="addeval">+</button>
                <p><strong>Click me to add your self evaluation!</strong></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="planchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="deadlinechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi unfortunately this didn't seem to change anything, still displaying nothing

Comment: Yes so the data base has columns title for the project title, id which is just a unique number automatically given to each row, deadlineMet which is VARCHAR but will always be Yes or No, same goes for rows plan and scope, then grade is also a string and can be A,B,C,D,E or F

Comment: sorry, just wanted to confirm the data was loaded properly on the page -- once the page loads, right click and view page source, look for the sections under `arrayToDataTable` to see if the arrays were created properly, don't really see anything else it could be...